# Java Heap Space: Out of Memory - no garbage collection?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

I have limited knowledge when it comes to the JVM and Heap Space so I'm trying to understand some behavior that we're seeing.

There's a situation where a user can request data that exceeds our heap space and therefore causes an OOM: Java Heap Space. Okay, that makes sense and we understand why that's happening.

After the OOM occurs, I notice that the amount of memory reported being used is the heap size + what our application normally runs at... however, after the OOM it doesn't appear to get garbage collected and return to normal memory levels; it just stays high. Is that expected? Apologies for such a simple question, I wasn't sure where to find this information elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here's what the code boils down to - we (mistakenly) allow a user to fetch too large of a range and when we try and return the `<List>` of objects it's causing the OOM error (at least that's my theory)

What in this code would cause an object to not get cleaned up?

```
public List<Class> getClassesByRange(Timestamp startDate, Timestamp endDate) {
    final Session session = this.sessionManager.openNewSession();

    try {
        final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Class.class);

        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("sorting"));
        criteria.setFetchMode("someObject", FetchMode.JOIN);
        criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("createDateTime", startDate));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("createDateTime", endDate));

        return criteria.list();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that your application is not making those objects eligible for garbage collection. Please check the code.

Comment: @joshft91 Without the code the best I can do is point you in the right direction: https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I updated my post with a code example. Thanks for the post as well about GC - I will definitely read it!

Comment: I would look at what objects are being retained after an OOME by taking a heap dump and see why references to them are being retained.

Comment: How do you determine how much memory is "used"? The JVM will normally not return memory to the OS. This does not mean that it is not garbage collected.

Comment: @Henry - good question. We're running our application in Openshift and they have a 'metrics' tab that I'm looking at ... it's not very good at all so it's certainly possible that those objects were GC'd

Comment: Well, *after* the OOME, there is no reason to perform garbage collection. It’s done *before* the OOME trying to avoid the OOME. So if the objects become unreachable after the OOME they will stay in the heap (at least according to the number claiming to tell you about the “used” memory) until there is a new actual reason to perform garbage collection.

Comment: Either trigger a manual gc after the event or take a heap dump to inspect whether some objects have been leaked.